# Symmetric potential well different solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I have solved $H|\psi\rangle=E_{n}|\psi\rangle$ with $V(x)=0$ from $-a<x<a$ and $\infty$ otherwise.
If I propose a solution of the form $\psi(x)=A_{n}e^{ikx}+B_{n}e^{-ikx}$ I arrive to the solution
$$
\psi(x)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}
  \sin \left(
    \frac{n\pi}{2} \left(\frac{x}{L}-1 \right)
  \right)$$
for $n$ natural.
If I propose a solution of the form 
$$\psi(x)=A_{n}\sin(kx)+B_{n}\cos(kx) \, .$$
I arrive to the solution
$$
\psi(x)
=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\cos \left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a} \right) & \text{n odd} \\
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{a} \right) & \text{n even }
   \end{cases}
$$

Both solutions with the same energies. However, when plotting both solutions, I see they're not equal. But I cannot find any mistakes on my procedures.

Comment: I think your L =a the width of the well.Try expanding the first solution in terms of sine and cosine function .I think it will be general solution (a combination of two solutions for n odd and even)

Comment: They are equal up to a phase factor of $-1$, so they are basically equal. Or equivalently $A_n, B_n$ are only fixed by the boundary conditions and normalization up to a phase factor $e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: The solution for n=odd matches my solution, but for n=even, plots are not equal even if consider an extra minus sign. However, the second solution for n=2 matches the first solution for n=4

Answer (score 1):

Solutions coincide for n=odd and an extra minus sign (wavefunctions are the same up to a phase factor, in this case $e^{i\pi}$). For n=even the solution from the piecewise function is the same than the first one for N=2n. Therefore they describe the same physical solution